# How to use NuSoap.php in my module with PSR-4 (Drupal 8)?

Tags: php, namespaces, drupal-8

I create module and want use NuSoap.php file.

```
bpay
- src
-- Controller
--- BpayController.php
-- Lib
--- NuSoap.php
```

BpayController.php :

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\bpay\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\bpay\Lib\nusoap;

class BpayController extends ControllerBase {

  private $client;

  public function new() {
    \Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();
    $client = new nusoap_client('https://example.org/pgw?wsdl');
    .
    .
    .
  return $build;
  }
}
```

NuSoap.php :

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\bpay\Lib;
.
.
.
```

When I run page, Show this error:

The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later. Error: Class 'Drupal\bpay\Controller\nusoap_client' not found in Drupal\bpay\Controller\BpayController->new() (line 26 of modules\bpay\src\Controller\BpayController.php).

How can I fix this error ?

Comment: have you defined `nusoap_client` class in `NuSoap.php`?

Comment: @SahilGulati Yes.

Comment: @SahilGulati Where is your answer ?!?!! Are you delete that ?

Comment: I have deleted that just because it was of no use for you,

Comment: !!!   Yesterday's earthquake in our area and I did not already have access to my system  !!!

Comment: Who can help me ?

Comment: You could use https://github.com/econea/nusoap, which is composer-based and seems like it supports modern versions of PHP. Or maybe install the SOAP extension for PHP.

Comment: @mradcliffe How can do this without composer ?

Comment: You wouldn't. You would use composer because there are versions of nusoap that support it.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will work fine,

1. I am assuming your class loader is working fine.
2. Class is defined as same name `nusoap_client`

**Change this to:**

```
use Drupal\bpay\Lib\nusoap;
```

**This:**

```
use Drupal\bpay\Lib\nusoap_client as nusoap_client;
```

Comment: The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Error: Class 'Drupal\bpay\Lib\nusoap_client' not found in Drupal\bpay\Controller\BpayController->new() (line 26 of modules\bpay\src\Controller\BpayController.php).

Comment: do one thing include `Drupal\bpay\Lib\NuSoap.php` this and try again

Comment: @user7549259 is it working while you are including file?

Comment: Drupal\bpay\Lib\NuSoap.php => ParseError: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';' in Composer\Autoload\includeFile()